# Find all integers $n$ such that $(n - 1)^2 + 3$ divides $n^3 + 2023$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

**Problem:** Find all integers $n$ such that $(n - 1)^2 + 3$ divides $n^3 + 2023$.

**My Work:**

$(n - 1)^2 + 3 = n^2 - 2n + 4$, which is always greater than 0 for all integers n.

Therefore, if $n^2 - 2n + 4$ divides $n^3 + 2023$, then $n^3 + 2023 >= n^2 - 2n + 4$.
We can also introduce an integer k into this, but we get left with $n^3 + 2023 = k * (n^2 - 2n + 4)$.

After getting this inequality and equation, I am not really sure how to continue. I would really appreciate some help! Thank you so much!

Comment: You should indicate where this problem comes from, specifically whether it's a 2023 contest, ongoing or not.

Comment: Do you know how to divide polynomials?

Comment: Write $n^3+2023 = (n^2-2n+4)(n+2)+2015$. Then you need $2015$ to be a multiple of $n^3+2023$, which will only happen if $n$ is negative and not very large in magnitude.

Comment: @dxiv I am not too sure. I asked my friend for some algebra problems for practice because I wanted to get better at math competitions, so he sent me this problem. I doubt that it is from any ongoing competition because he is already in college and is not participating in any competitions anymore.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but I think the numbers are too big for me to divide right now :(

Comment: They aren't too big.

Comment: You could get that via polynomial division. I was able to get that in my head.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh yes! Sorry, I do not know why I suddenly just forgot about polynomial division! You are right, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: List the positive divisors of $2015 : \{1,5,13,31,65,155,403,2015\}$. When you subtract $3$, only one of these divisors is a perfect square.

Comment: @mcd, don't we need $2015$ to be a multiple of $(n-1)^2+3$?

Comment: I think I got it!!! The answers are n= -19, 21

Comment: @dxiv My friend just responded, he said that this problem (and the list of algebra problems he gave me) was from a math meet involving a couple of high schools that he helped organize recently.

Comment: @Lozenges you don't even need the explicit factors. Since $2015=5×13×31$ all factors must end in $1,3,$ or $5$ and subtracting $3$ to get $(n-1)^2$ gives a terminal digit of $8,0,$ or $2$. Only $0$ is consistent with a square and that requires another preceding $0$, so $(n-1)^2+3=13×31$ is the only viable candidate.

Comment: Yes, @Gerry Myerson of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written above,
$$
n^3+2023=(n^2-2n+4)(n+2)+2015
$$
so you need
$$
2015=((n-1)^2+3)k
$$
for some integer $k$. Since $k$ must divide $2015$, we have $\pm k\in\{1, 5, 13, 31, 65, 155, 403, 2015\}$ (see the comments; you also formally probably need the negative ones). However, since $(n-1)^2+3>0$, we must have $k>0$, so $\frac{2015}k\in\{1, 5, 13, 31, 65, 155, 403, 2015\}$
$$
|n-1|\in \{\sqrt{1-3}, \sqrt{5-3}, \sqrt{13-3}, \sqrt{31-3}, \sqrt{65-3}, \sqrt{155-3}, \sqrt{403-3}, \sqrt{2015-3}\}=\{\sqrt{-2}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{10}, \sqrt{28} ,\sqrt{ 62} ,\sqrt{ 152} ,20 ,\sqrt{ 2012}\}
$$
where only one is an integer (see the comments too) so since $n$ must be an integer we get $|n-1|=20$, i.e. $n=21$ or $n=-19$.